# Введенные цифры в Plain Text не парсятся в int C#

Tags: c#, text

edictText1 - Это Plain Text (куда я ввожу данные, как консоль)

```
EditText editText1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1); 
int ba = Int32.Parse(editText1.Text);
```

Если ввести данные, допустим единицу, то он не спарсит ее. В чем проблема, кто знает? 
Может быть есть метод который парсит нормально? 
Работаю в Xamarin.Android

Comment: А что означает «не парсит»? Что происходит?

Comment: Ну, т.е. он не переводит из Editable (это формат EditText) в Int. 
Я ввожу данные с клавиатуры телефона и он должен был мне сделать математическую операцию с этими данными и вывести в ответ. В итоге он мне ничего не выводит, т.к. данные не переводятся в Int

Comment: Странно. При неудачном разборе числа должно было быть выброшено исключение. А что показывает отладчик?

Comment: Он мне и говорит то, что у него не получилось конвертировать число. Вот что выдает при запуске на телефоне: System.FormatException

Comment: Это я уже отошел от самой логики и пытался выявить ошибку. Так что это при самом Parse, а если я буду использовать TryParse, то он будет всегда выдавать False( даже если я введу число).

Comment: А как выглядит содержимое `editText1.Text` под отладчиком?

Comment: Я не совсем понял вашего вопроса, но что-то мне удалось найти, наведя курсором на сам editText1, мне выдало : Function evaluation timeout.

Comment: Ну у вас в отладчике есть окно Watch, вот туда пропишите `editText1.Text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `editText1.Text.ToString();` чтобы получить строку, а не текст и выполняйте парсинг.

А так переведите логику парсинга и расчета в Core(Xamarin PCL/Net.Standard) проект и используйте там абстрагированные от платформы операции парсинга из строки в число. Вам может понадобиться это для других проектов(iOS, UWP) в данной приложении.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number

Плюс диагностика:
Можете создать переменную до этого

```
var inputedText = editText1.Text.ToString();
```

и вывести ее на консоль.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Debug.WriteLine(inputedText);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я пытался использовать editText1.getText().ToString()
Не могу понять почему не работало, оказывается это работает только на Java. Спасибо!